# Int Variables Successfully Assigned from String Value Without Explicit Conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm curious as to how SQL Server is able to successfully give integer variables values when they are assigned as a string. I'd expect the assignment for `@Int1` would result in a conversion failure but it works the same as the assignment for `@Int`.

```
DECLARE @Int INT = CAST('2' AS INT)
SELECT @Int

DECLARE @Int1 INT = '2'
SELECT @Int1
```

Additionally, if you assign an int variable to an empty string it results in the variable given a 0 value.

```
DECLARE @Int3 INT = ''
SELECT @Int3
```

I did a search looking for some sort of documentation of this behavior but all I could find was guides on how to use the cast and convert functions.

Does anyone have a good reference or explanation as to how/ why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server implicitly converts data types whenever you try to assign, combine, or compare values of different types if one of them can be implicitly converted to the other.

This is well documented in [Data type conversion (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017):

> Data types can be converted in the following scenarios:
>
> - When data from one object is moved to, compared with, or combined with data from another object, the data may have to be converted from the data type of one object to the data type of the other.
> - When data from a Transact-SQL result column, return code, or output parameter is moved into a program variable, the data must be converted from the SQL Server system data type to the data type of the variable. *(Irrelevant to the question)*

Right under this there's a paragraph entitled **Implicit and explicit conversion** which states:

> Data types can be converted either implicitly or explicitly.
>
> Implicit conversions are not visible to the user. SQL Server automatically converts the data from one data type to another. For example, when a smallint is compared to an int, the smallint is implicitly converted to int before the comparison proceeds.

Further down this page there's a table that shows all data type possible conversions - both explicit and implicit.

There is also a page called [Data type precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), documenting what type would be implicitly converted to what type when the implicit conversion is a result of a calculation - for example -  `1 + '2'` would result with `3` since integer has a higher precedence than char:

```
DECLARE @Int int = 1,
        @Char char(1) = '2'

SELECT @int + @Char As ImplicitConversionDemo
```

Result:

```
ImplicitConversionDemo
3
```